# Javascript or Jquery Alter Form/Input Ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a page that has a form above the fold. When the user scrolls down on the page and the form is no longer visible a fixed banner appears at the top of the page and contains the same form. When the user scrolls back up and can view the original form again, the banner disappears. Due to constraints of the site that I am working on the two forms need to have identical ids and input ids. However, submitting the forms now creates an issue since both have the same ids. I would want to use jquery or javascript to alter the forms and its input's ids when scrolling. Let's assume the form is as follows:

```
<form id="formid">
    <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" value="name" placeholder="name/>
    <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="name" placeholder="name/>
</form>
```

This form appears in the main div in the form:

```
<div id="main">
    <form id="formid">
        <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" value="name" placeholder="name/>
        <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="name" placeholder="name/>
    </form>
</div>
```

The banner form which is hidden by default until the user scrolls is as follows:

```
<div id="banner">
    <form id="formid">
        <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" value="name" placeholder="name/>
        <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" value="name" placeholder="name/>
    </form>
</div>
```

How can I toggle the ids in these two forms so that when the banner is hidden would have different ids than the form in the main div. Then when I scroll the ids of the two forms would swap. If there is a better solution for this, I'm open to all possibilities.

My scrolling function is as follows:

```
var showTop = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        // get the height of #wrap
        var h = $("body").height();
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (showTop) {
            if (y > (h * .13) && y < (h * .75)) {
                // if we are show keyboardTips
                $("#banner").fadeIn("fast");
            } else {
                $('#banner').fadeOut('fast');
            }
        }
    });
    $('.closeBanner').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.banner').hide();
        showTop = false;
    });
})
```

Comment: Why don't you use just one <form> and use CSS to display wherever you want, instead of two html structures? You will have just once the ids, and your submit will not shout.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: You can only use ID once on a page.    
You should consider other solutions like using one form only with one ID, and change the styling using the 'css' or 'add/removeClass' function from JQUERY.